# How can I make a struct with a function that can be changed in c++?

Tags: c++, struct

I want to make a struct that can be initialized so that without using if or switch statements, the struct shows the function that the user have chosen at the beginning. Similar to `readonly` in C#.
So after declaring a struct `S`, containing a function `f()`, for example, `f()` should work **different** if I declare the structure as `S("a")` or `S("b")`.

1. Is it possible?
2. If it is, how?

Comment: Read about [template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization)

Comment: something like a `std::map<std::string, void(*)()>`?

Comment: What's "differently"?

Comment: @Amadeusz template specialization won't bring anything since this is a runtime parameter.

Comment: You can create your lambda function in the constructor of your structure depending of the arguments passed to the constructor.

Comment: @Light capturing lambdas have incompatible types. Non-capturing lambdas would have to decay to function pointers to be assignable, at which point you may as well just use a named function

Comment: Yeah, when I asked what's "differently" I wasn't taking a jab at your grammar or spelling. You need to define what you want to change. The functions behavior? The number of parameters?

Comment: @user1810087 - Thank you for assuming malice or stupidity.

Comment: @StoryTeller well, maybe the "differently" was right :s But I have a question : do you mean that there are ways to get multiple inputs like printf() ?

Comment: @user5876164 - Some, yes. I only wanted you to better define your goals so you would get better answers. But you seem to have accepted one already, so it's moot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes

You can use a [function pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_functions), or other callable object. You can put those things in a map, and lookup in the map when you construct an `S`

```
void f_A() { std::cout << "called a"; }
void f_B() { std::cout << "called b"; }

std::map<std::string, void(*)()> functions = { { "a", f_A }, { "b", f_B } };

struct S
{
    S(std::string id) : f(functions[id]) {}
    void(*f)();
}

int main()
{
    S a("a");
    S b("b");
    a.f();
    b.f();
    return 0;
}
```

If you need `S` to have other state, and the `f`s to use it, you can modify the example thus:

```
struct S; // need to forward declare S

void f_A(S* s) { std::cout << "called a with " << s->foo; }
void f_B(S* s) { std::cout << "called b with " << 2 * s->foo; }

std::map<std::string, void(*)(S*)> functions = { { "a", f_A }, { "b", f_B } };

struct S
{
    S(std::string id, int foo_) : f_impl(functions[id]), foo(foo_) {}
    void f() { f_impl(this); }
    int foo;
private:
    void (*f_impl)(S*);
}
```

Comment: Does it take more time than getting the function through if or switch to get the function using map? What may be the way to do such things fast, in the range you know?

Comment: Here the map is accessed *once* per object. An `if` (you can't `switch` on strings) would be run each time you called an `S`'s `f`. But most importantly, write code you *understand*, measure (**don't guess**) where the performance *matters*, and *only then* make things less understandable for speed

Comment: Just as a side note, you're typically better off using `std::unordered_map` if it's available (C++11 onward). This is average case constant time lookup vs logarithmic.

Comment: @NicholasBetsworth sure, but for ~2 elements it basically doesn't matter

Comment: I don't much about function pointers, but in f(functions[id] , don't you need to declare f somewhere ? Also, can you explain void(*f)(); ?

Comment: Why not creating enums instead of a map, if only want to switch on name?

Comment: @Caleth Of course, but this minimal example doesn't necessarily correspond to his actual use case. It's potentially the reason he wishes to avoid control statements.

Comment: @KaizerSozay `f` is the other member of `S`. It has type `void (*)()`. The syntax for declaring function pointer types is different to most other type syntaxes. (references to arrays are similar). The type just means "pointer to function taking no arguments and returning `void`"

Comment: @Chiel the question was asking how to avoid a switch block

Comment: @Caleth. I know, but if the use case contains many, many switches, there might be cheaper solutions than a map, if the number and implementation of the functions is decided compile time.

Comment: @Chiel at which point `std::unordered_map` would probably be faster still

Comment: Why not using [std::function<void()>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)? Like `std::map<std::string, std::function<void()> >`... So you also could bind to class methods... + it's more c++-'ish'.

Comment: @user1810087 `std::function<void()>` has significantly more overhead than `void(*)()`. You only need it if you must hold arbitrary callable objects. In this example we don't.